# How can I setup a delete Trigger on AWS RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, mariadb, amazon-rds

I have a setup on AWS RDS with MariaDB 10.3. I have several DBs on the RDS instance. I'm trying to replicate a table (`routes`) from one DB (`att`) to another DB (`pro`) using triggers. I have triggers for `create`, `update` and `delete`. The `create` and `update` triggers works fine while the `delete` trigger gives the error message below. I've tested all triggers locally and they work.

My trigger looks like this.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` TRIGGER routes_delete AFTER DELETE ON 
`routes` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  DELETE FROM `pro`.`routes`
   WHERE `route_id` = OLD.route_id;
END
```

Error message

```
Query execution failed

Reason:
SQL Error [1442] [HY000]: (conn:349208) Can't update table 'routes' in             
stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which     
invoked this stored function/trigger
Query is : DELETE FROM `att`.routes WHERE route_code = 78 AND company_id = 3
```

I don't understand what other statement is using the `routes` table since there is nothing else linked to it. What adjustment is needed to get this work on AWS RDS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what other statement is using the `routes` table

The "other" query is the query that invoked the trigger.

```
...is already used by [the] statement which invoked this stored function/trigger
```

A trigger is not allowed to modify its own table.  `BEFORE INSERT` and `BEFORE UPDATE` triggers can modify the *current row* before it is written to the table using the `NEW` alias, but that is the extent to which a trigger can modify the table where it is defined.

Triggers [are subject to all the same limitations](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/trigger-limitations/)   as stored functions, and a stored function...

> Cannot make changes to a table that is already in use (reading or writing) by the statement invoking the stored function.
>
> https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/stored-function-limitations/

Comment: I understand that a trigger can't update the table that triggered it but in this case the trigger is triggered on delete statements for the ``att`.`routes`` table while it should delete entries in  the ``pro`.`routes`` table.

Comment: @g3blv oh! Yes, I overlooked the fact that these are two different tables with the same name.  The explanation in this case is that you have a loop of triggers -- perhaps inadvertently -- or maybe created one in the wrong place.  `USE pro;` then `SHOW TRIGGERS;`.  Does `pro.routes` have a delete trigger that you created accidentally?  That would be an easy mistake to make.  Or does `pro.routes` have a trigger you intended to create, that modifies another table, that also has a trigger, where trigger actions are eventually cascading back to `att.routes`?

Comment: You are correct. I had by mistake added a delete trigger to `pro.routes`. I removed it and now it works. Should I mark your reply correct even though the solution is in the comment?